# How to tell which server a cache item is on?

Tags: c#, caching, load-balancing

I have a site on two load balanced servers, and am using `HttpRuntime.Cache`. Is it possible to differentiate between which server a cache item is on, in my C# code? Either when adding or getting the item?

Comment: Forget asp.net caching....switch to AppFabric cache...your life will be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpRuntime.Cache is not shared accross our servers so every item put in the cache will be cached twice : once in every server.

If you want to share your cache use http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingConfiguringAndUsingWindowsServerAppFabricAndTheVelocityMemoryCacheIn10Minutes.aspx

Comment: Right, there are two cache items, one on each server, and I want to know which server the item in question is on. I do not want to share my cache.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602810/is-there-a-way-to-view-the-httpruntime-cache